# How to do a unique search in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm trying to do a search in Splunk in which I'm trying to narrow it down to a unique substring.

An example of my query so far would be:

```
host=node-1 AND "userCache:"
```

Which returns something like this:

```
Time                Event
06/04/2021-blah     Cache miss: userCache:  tjohnson
                    host=node-1
06/04/2021-blah     Cache miss: userCache:  sbaca
                    host=node-1
06/04/2021-blah     Cache miss: userCache:  tjohnson
                    host=node-1
```

What I want to do, though, is to return only one unique value based on what comes after userCache:

In the above example, only two results would be returned - one for tjohnson and one for sbaca.  The additional tjohnson would be stripped since there is already a tjohnson in the results.

Any suggestions?

Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That calls for the `dedup` command, which removes duplicates from the search results.  First, however, we need to extract the user name into a field.  We'll do that using `rex`.

````
index=foo ```Always specify an index``` host=node-1 AND "userCache:"
| rex "userCache:\s*(?<user>\w+)"
| dedup user
````

Comment: `dedup` is pretty indeal *most* of the time